# Error 401 - Invalid username or password

Tags: google-app-engine

when I enter email and password to deploy in google app engine launcher the following error message: "Invalid username or password. 
08/19/2014 19: 38: 16,573 appcfg.py:2411 ERROR An error occurred processing file ': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
Error 401: --- begin server output --- "and the new url xxxxxxxx.appspot.com not work.

Comment: Well??? post the contents of your `appcfg.py` file.

Comment: I think @barakmanos meant to say the content of your app.yaml file.

Comment: @IanGSY: Well, kind of... I mean, I did think that OP should post the contents of this file as well, but I didn't bother to mention it in the comment. In essence, we need both - the yaml file and the py file that it refers to under `- url: .* script: xxx.app`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to deploy my go application, try to use `-oauth` flag :

`goapp deploy -oauth myapp/`

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661736/cannot-deploy-with-goapp-invalid-username-or-password/26106772#26106772), and it worked for me.

I'm not sure for the other language, maybe `-oauth` or `--oauth2` will work.