# Cannot deploy with goapp - invalid username or password

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Getting an `invalid username or password` error after trying to sign in with

```
goapp deploy myapp/
```

following the [Google App Engine Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/uploading) tutorial.

Comment: Also, in both the tutorial and the error, there is a reference to `username`, but the `goapp deploy` is asking for an `email`. A bit confusing.

Comment: Did you try oauth flag? `goapp deploy -oauth -application <projectid>`

Comment: Ok, it works with the flag. Interesting.

Comment: I have same problem. I'm using google app engine launcher and constantly getting error that email or password is invalid. Can you tell me how to deploy using -oauth flag?

Comment: Exactly like a normal deploy, but with `-oauth` flag specified after `goapp deploy` but before the app path (if specified). ntsh gave an example above. Hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of having the answer as an actual answer:

use the following

> goapp deploy -oauth -application

and it will work.  Credit to @ntsh for this :)

Comment: Yes, but it still does not answer the question as to why this is happening. The tutorial clearly states using the `goapp deploy myapp/`.

Comment: Documentation may need an update. You can feedback directly from the tutorial I think (should be a button top right of your screen).

Answer (score 0):

`goapp` seems to be lacking in documentation. Anyway it uses `appcfg.py`, so you can directly update app with:

```
appcfg.py update . --noauth_local_webserver
```